# Dropdown inside jQuery accordion interference on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a sidebar with a jQuery accordion inside. The accordion opens/closes on hover. I use hoverintent too.

I wanted to put a select dropdown inside the accordion, but the issue is this:

When the dropdown extends beyond the content of the accordion "pane" (which is what I want), and I want to select an option inside the dropdown, then the accordion pane closes, triggered by the hover event. Obviously the dropdown then disappears as well, making it impossible to make a choice.

Doe someone know a way around this?